# Why debian8 64 bit version can't be installed into my 64 bit virtualbox?

Tags: debian, virtualbox, 64bit, x86

```
$ uname  -a
Linux hwy 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The virtualbox installed on my pc is 64 bit version too,it is installed this way .

```
dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.10-104061~Debian~jessie_amd64.deb
```

Now I want to install debian8.2  64 bit version on my virtualbox,it can't.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable  enable VT-x/AMD-v in the host PC BIOS to be able to run 64 bit guests.

Otherwise as you have found out, several emulation framework/technologies will only allow you to use 32 bit guests.

Here is an article about [how to enable Intel Virtualization Technology (vt-x) and amd-v in BIOS](http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios)